# Docker WordPress Sub-directory - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, docker

I'm creating a WordPress blog based on a docker container with an official image. When I use no directories, WordPress works fine but when I use the "/blog" directory using WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL it's given me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on /blog/wp-admin/install.php (302).

How can I achieve docker WordPress with directories?

**Docker Image**

```
docker pull WordPress: latest
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM WordPress: latest

COPY config/ /var/www/html/

RUN a2enmod
```

*config folder has custom wp-config.php with WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL*

**wp-config.php**

```
<?php
    /**
     * The base configuration for WordPress
     *
     * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
     * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
     * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
     *
     * This file contains the following configurations:
     *
     * * MySQL settings
     * * Secret keys
     * * Database table prefix
     * * ABSPATH
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
     *
     * @package WordPress
     */
    
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/blog' ); 
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/blog' );
    
    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
    define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );
    
    /** MySQL database username */
    define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );
    
    /** MySQL database password */
    define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
    
    /** MySQL hostname */
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
    
    /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
    define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
    
    /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
    define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
    
    /**#@+
     * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
     *
     * Change these to different unique phrases!
     * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
     * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
    define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );
    
    /**#@-*/
    
    /**
     *

 WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

// define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
#
```

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In my case, this resolves the issue.

also, check extra work on my **wp-config.php**

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

/blog/wp-admin/ here blog is sub directory path.